# How to delay the next command in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in a situation where I want to put some delay between some lines of javascript code like following :

```
function sayHello(){
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Hello";
// some delay of about 2 seconds 
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "I am a programmer";
```

}

Comment: Do not delay synchronously. This will cause the page to become unresponsive

Answer (score -3):

Try `setTimeout("YOUR CODE HERE", 2000 /*(2 seconds in miliseconds)*/)`
You can read more [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: This question has been asked before

Comment: Passing strings as the first argument to `setTimeout` is (a) inefficient (b) does weird things with scope and (c) makes debugging harder. When using `setTimeout`, pass a function, not a string.

Comment: And W3Schools is awful. In this particular case they aren't so bad that they recommend passing a string, but bad enough that they don't even mention it is possible (which is really bad for an API reference!)